# OpenGL Hardware rendering not working on Kubuntu guest on Virtualbox

Tags: opengl, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, kubuntu

I have installed Kubunto 10.04 (Android project recommended development environment) on Virtualbox 4.1.16. I have installed the Virtualbox guest additions and have full-screen graphics on the guest. I am trying to work with OpenGL but I get the following messages (e.g. for glxinfo):

> OpenGL Warning: Host doesn't accept our version 5.1. Make sure you
>   have appropriate additions installed! OpenGL Warning: Failed to
>   connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.

I have set the 3D acceleration support for the VM in the Virtualbox console.

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: You can easily develop for Android also on Windows or MacOSX. There is no need to use Linux for that.

Comment: I am talking about the Android source project (http://source.android.com/)... I think it's possible to build it from either Linux of Mac OS X. Anyways, this is a more general question.

Comment: Your question better fits SuperUser. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in StackOverflow, here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576996/how-do-i-run-the-android-emulator-after-a-build

Or, better, in the Android emulator site:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

(I learnt it the hard way: I was trying to use a XP SP3 virtual machine for Android development)